# How to find the correct form of verb in ambiguous subjects.?

Tags: ambiguity, verb-agreement, compound-subjects

*Neelima, my best friend / and the Head of this department / are leaving / on Monday./no error*

I came across this sentence in my exam, I couldn't figure out if the head of this department and Neelima are/is the same person or not?

Comment: What clues are you using to decide between the options?

Comment: You have to decide how many are leaving.

Comment: The answer will depend on if your region/style dictates use of the Oxford comma. Its absence here may be be intended to change how the sentence is parsed, or simply be a stylistic omission that results in unresolvable ambiguity.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But if they were the same person, I should have written: **Neelima, my best friend and Head of this department, is leaving on Monday.** But omitting **the** is a case of preference rather than than a requirement.

Comment: @RonaldSole can we remove article "the", I thought it was not possible .

Comment: @Rishirajchauhan The omission of the article (definite or indefinite) is common in many instances, such as those illustrated here. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/can-several-nouns-share-one-article.1542128/   (Google **omission of the article), So you can say: **Peter is the president and founder of the company**, without repeating **the**. Ditto in my example.

Comment: The sentence is in dire need of recasting. Punctuation involving zero and /or commas only will not disambiguate. Neelima (my best friend), and the Head of this department   are both leaving / on Monday./

Comment: As written in the question, we have "A, B and C are leaving". Even if the A, B and C are odd as is.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence either refers to two or three people, depending on how it's parsed. The Oxford comma, or serial comma, can be used to avoid some of this ambiguity. The Oxford comma is placed before the "and" preceding the final member of a list, and indicates that the last item and penultimate item are not actually a single item. When written with the Oxford comma, the sentence would appear as

> Neelima, my best friend, and the Head of the department are leaving on Monday.

The Oxford comma above indicates that "my best friend" and "the Head of this department" are distinct items. It does not disambiguate whether "Neelima" and "my best friend" are the same person or not, so this construction could refer to either two or three people - I'd probably interpret it as three people, since the sentence could easily have been written as "My best friend Neelima and the Head of the department" to unambiguously denote two, rather than three people.

The lack of the Oxford comma in the actual text may or may not be significant, depending on if you are in a region or writing according to a style that mandates it. If this is written in a style that does use the Oxford comma, the lack of one indicates that "my best friend" and "the Head of the department" are *not* distinct items and are actually the same person. The sentence in this case indicates just one person, Neelima, who is both your best friend and head of the department, since there is no "and" between Neelima and the rest of the description.

If this is written in a style that does not use the Oxford comma, the sentence cannot be parsed unambiguously. It could refer to one, two, or three people, depending on if it's parsed as

> (Neelima, my best friend and the head of the department)

> (Neelima, my best friend) and (the head of the department), or

> (Neelima), (my best friend) and (the head of the department)

The listing of subjects doesn't give many clues about how many people are being referred to, but we can infer from the use of the verb *are* instead of *is* that we are referring to either two or three people, and rule out the case where Neelima is both your best friend and the head of the department.

Overall, it's not a very well constructed sentence because it can be parsed in so many ways, with little to indicate what the writer actually meant.

Comment: The best style is to use the Oxford comma where it serves to disambiguate, ditch it where this  alternative will disambiguate (covered on ELU), and rephrase where neither disambiguates (eg where a list item and an appositive are not distinguishable).

Comment: This is a good answer, and I have upvoted it. But I think it does not address why this is a terrible question for an exam. One reason it is a good answer is that it has elicited wise advice about how to use style guides in Edwin Ashworth’s comment.

Answer (score 0):

They are different persons.

If they were the same person, one of the choices should be in the singular.
Thus you could say:

> Neelima, my best friend and the Head of the department **is**
> leaving on Monday.

Comment: No. If there is only one person, then the appositive phrase should be uninterrupted: delete the comma after **friend**.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney, true. But then, the other comma must be also deleted. Right?

Comment: When an appositive phrase interrupts the flow of the sentence, a comma is required before it and after it, just as if the commas were brackets/parentheses.

Comment: The original poster wanted to know if “are” is correct. That depends on whether the intended subject is one person or more than one person. Assuming “are” is correct evades the entire issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to see answers that focus on punctuation, which is not part of the spoken language’s grammar at all. Discussion of punctuation comes down to discussion of style guides as evidenced by the references to the Oxford comma in this thread. This question, however, is about punctuation so we are forced to discuss it.

Let’s start with the spoken language, part of which involves the duration of pauses between words. Items in a list greater than two are given slightly longer pauses than usual.Appositional phrases are bracketed with even longer pauses.

> Neela slightly longer than usual pause my best friend slightly longer than usual pause and I are leaving on Monday

is how most native speakers would orally phrase the sentence if three people are intending to leave.

> Neela even longer pause my best friend even longer pause and I are leaving on Monday

is how most native speakers would orally phrase the sentence if two people are intending to leave and “my best friend” is an appositional phrase identifying Neela.

It is certainly possible that the intended difference in meaning between these two sentences consisting of identical words will be missed by a listener, but a clue will have been there. Style guides usually recommend commas in written English where there would be a pause in spoken English. But a comma cannot indicate the slight difference in the lengths of the pause used to separate items in a list and the pause used to set off an appositional phrase.

The specific question is unanswerable.

If you are expected to use the Oxford comma, the given sentence is not properly punctuated whether two distinct people are going or three. If you are expected to eschew the Oxford comma, the given sentence is properly punctuated if and only if three distinct people are going rather than two, but the question does not give the information needed to make that determination.

It is a badly designed question for an exam. Yet there is a lesson to be learned. Punctuation will not always prevent ambiguity in part because there is no style guide that is used universally. Word choice, word order and the use of relative clauses are more powerful than commas.

> The head of the department and Neela, who is my best friend, are leaving Monday

unambiguously refers to two people.

> The head of the department along with my best friend and Neela are leaving Monday

unambiguously refers to three people

**EDIT** I see that I have neglected the precise question asked by the original poster.

If the subject of the sentence is one person, then the punctuation of the sentence and the verb are both wrong. The verb should be “is.”

If the subject of the sentence is more than one person, the verb is fine, but the punctuation may be wrong.

The intended meaning of the sentence being asked about is ambiguous, and whether that sentence is in error or not depends both on that unknown meaning and which style guide someone considers authoritative.

Awful exam question.